# $.getJSON() fails in chrome but works fine in ie

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, rest, call

```
$.getJSON(loginURL,
                            {
                            });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {Accept: "application/json"},
                        crossDomain: false,
                        url: loginURL,
                        success: function(loginFlag)
                        {



                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {


                        }
                    }
                    );
```

The loginURL is configured using context name and parameters required to be handled by the server . The call works fine in ie, but fails in chrome. The error method of getJson is called when i tried from chrome but success is called when attempted with ie. 
eg: var loginURL = "/GameApplicationWeb_v4/service/checkusercredentials/uname/name/password/name@game"

Comment: Use Fiddler or the developer tools' Network tab to figure out what the server is returning when the call is sent from Chrome.

Comment: Yes the call has been sent from chrome. Now that i have added a few more header attributes to the code and now it's working .

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON(loginURL,
                            {
                            });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {Accept: "application/json"},
                        crossDomain: false,
                        url: loginURL,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(loginFlag)
                        {
                        }, 
                        error   ()
                         {
                         });
```

I have added a few more header attributes (aync & cache)and now it's working fine.